# Is /ɡ/ Germanic and /dʒ/ French in English ge-/gi- words?

Tags: english, etymology, pronunciation, germanic-languages, romance-languages

I've recently noticed that in English words starting with "ge-" or "gi-", when the "g" is pronounced /ɡ/, they tend to be etymologically Germanic, while the words where the "g" is pronounced /dʒ/ tend to be etymologically French (or possibly Latin). I'm sure there will be the odd exception here and there, such as words that come from neither Germanic or Latin sources, but is this an accurate observation?

Germanic:

- [get](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Etymology_1) - from Old Norse *geta*
- [giggle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giggle#Etymology) - unknown - perhaps from Middle English *gigen*
- [girl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/girl#Etymology) - probably from Old English **gyrle*, **gyrele*, a diminutive form of Proto-Germanic **gurwijaz*

via French / Latin:

- [gentle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentle#Etymology) - from Old French *gentil*
- [giraffe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giraffe#Etymology) - from French *giraffe*, from Arabic
- [gist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gist#Etymology) - from Old French *gist*

Comment: This has a fair amount of overlap with this ELU question, you may want to take a look: [Do the words with non-palatalized pronunciation of g/c (“get”, “give”) always have a Germanic origin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174621)

Comment: See also this question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23015/why-does-begin-have-g-instead-of-j-if-its-from-pg-ginnan

Answer (score 5):

The fun answer is:

English should not have **any** inherited words beginning in *ge-/gi-*.

The reason is the so-called Anglo-Frisian palatisation that shifted of original Germanic **ge-/gi-* to *ye-/yi-*. Whenever there is a word beginning in *ge-* or *gi-* some explanation is needed:

- It might be a loan word from Old Norse. This applies to the most common cases (get, give)
- Levelling has unified a split pattern to restore the original g in the *anlaut* (goose/geese might be an example, to begin (began, begun) might be another one)
- It might be a loan word from some other language
- It might be an onomatopoetic word (this could apply for to giggle)
- The vowel e/i might have developed from another vowel (a, o, or u) at a time when the Anglo-Frisian palatisation was no longer active

The words beginning in /dʒ/ are all loans, this sound wasn't originally in Old English and was imported from Norman French.

Comment: The explanation for "geese" that I am familar with is that by the time umlaut of this kind occured, palatalization of velars next to front vowels was no longer an active sound change. I guess it could be called analogy/leveling but there are no exceptions that I know of

Comment: E.g. on Google Books I found "A caeg to Old English syllable structure" which mentions this: https://books.google.com/books?id=zPRbq-qsK5kC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=umlaut+velar+old+English+palatal&source=bl&ots=p4J0_dTPfz&sig=Eu2IYZbMrxKk_W-jruZD0fnt8lw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj43qvj94HVAhUq5oMKHVb6Boc4ChDoAQgsMAE#v=onepage&q=umlaut%20velar%20old%20English%20palatal&f=false

Comment: And does the same apply to *ga-/go-/gu-*?  I see many examples like *gander*, *gather*, *game*, *ghost*, *good* and *gallows* that did not shift, and a few like *gate* that are apparently *yate* in some dialect, and there are simply very few English words like *yard* that start with *y-* or *ya-/yo-/yu-*.  A few others like *yoke* are odd like *year* in that they were *j-*, then supposedly *g-* for a time, then *y-* (ie *j-) again.  Seems like a hypercorrection in medieval writing and/or a battle between different continental dialects.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: The word yoke (High German Joch, Latin iugum, Greek zygon) never had an initial /g/ (maybe except for some obscure dialects or hypercorrections) and I suppose the same holds for year (High German Jahr) . Yard (High German cognate Garten) is different, maybe it had an /e/ vowel at some time in at least some forms (High German plural is Gärten with an open e sound).

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer BTW, spelling variation is expected at a time when all original ge/gi-words are shifted and there is no difference between ge/gi and ye/yi.The same happens with Spanish (confusion of b and v) today.

Comment: I see, they were just spelling it *geoc* for a bit but saying *jok* the whole time.